# How to limit the collected data so as not to collect the entire tree of elements below it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

In this way, when scraping the `href` it also ends up collecting the layers below, such as the `level-3`, but I would like to specifically collect the `level-2`, what should I modify so that this doesn't happen?

This is the site:
https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/

Part of the commented code:

```
ls = soup.find('ul', class_='level-2').findAll('li')
    for i in ls:
        print(i.find('a')['href'])
    print('\n')
```

Full code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url = 'https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/'
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
ls = soup.find('ul', class_='level-2').findAll('li')
for i in ls:
    print(i.find('a')['href'])
print('\n')
```

Expected Output:

```
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/s13030/final-stages/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you onnly want the *direct* `<li>` children of the specific tag, just add the parameter `recursive=False`

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

url = 'https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/'
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
ls = soup.find('ul', class_='level-2').findAll('li',recursive=False)
for i in ls:
    print(i.find('a')['href'])
print('\n')
```

**Output:**

```
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/s13030/final-stages/
```

Comment: In this case it only collects ```current expanded```, but doesn't look for ```leaf```, is there any way to limit it to only the first level of ```li```? Or will I need to make two different calls to each one?

Comment: whats your expected output for this site/url?

Comment: Hi mate @chitown88 , thanks for support, i add in question!